# Select Rows with a Point that fall within a set of points that form a polygon from outside the DB

Tags: postgis

Using a front end Map UI, I have selected a polygon and received all the Lat/Long points from it. I want to send this data to a PostgreSQL PostGIS database table that has rows which stores a geometry Point in a column. I need to select all the rows that are inside of the polygon. How do I put the external polygon points into the SQL statement and pull the correct data?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer:

```
SELECT * FROM Your_Table
  WHERE ST_Within(geom, 
    ST_GeometryFromText('POLYGON((-104.53798595055618 31.54712467875706,
        -102.48477288296839 31.289207699238165,
        -102.68445701550822 30.006579157844246,
        -104.3434563387951 30.233933113969798,
        -104.53798595055618 31.54712467875706))',4326)
    );
```